# Meteor accounts login only working on localhost

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have Facebook, Google, and Twitter all working on localhost, but when I deploy the application to Modulus, all three are not working.  They are configured properly on the various developer sites with the callback URLs.  Each one gets hung up on the popup window, and there seems to be some sort of issue with the redirect.

Comment: Check out http://zach.is for the deployed application...

Comment: change your site url on your facebook app